# Store a variable Vector of integer as bpy.props

Tags: properties, vector

I am new in Blender dev. I am trying to create an add-on, and I need to store an array of integers. The problem is that I don't know the size of this array.
I used for testing the `IntVectorProperty`:

```
bpy.props.IntVectorProperty(
    name='Name',
    description='Desc',
    default=[0,0],
    subtype='NONE',
    size=2
)
```

But the size is a required field.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: There they create a new custom property that I can use as bpy.props, right? Ok, if this is the cleanest way to do it, I could give it a try. Thank you! 
I'd like to keep the question open. If I solve it I can provide the code for size varying int arrays

Comment: You might want to use a [CollectionProperty](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.CollectionProperty.html) instead which you can vary the size at runtime

Comment: Yes, the collection property solved my problem. Thanks